# How can I identify if the akka cluster is running on the kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, akka, akka-cluster

My akka cluster system can deployed both by VMs and kubernetes, how can I identify if the akka cluster is running on the kubernetes so that I do not need to config the cluster seeds node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way is just to identify if there has the namespace file in the system.

```
/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace
```